# How to make a field for a user to complete in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, user-input

i would like to know how to make a field for a user to complete it in cmd such like this would like look:

[CMD OUTPUT]Please type your Windows user name to continue:

[USER INPUT]-Joshua

[CMD OUTPUT]Thanks, now your password is "Billydog"

And if is possible to look like this.

Comment: See `set /p` http://ss64.com/nt/set.html (example therein)

Answer (score 1):

You can use set /p :

```
set /p "$Input=Please type your Windows user name to continue: "
echo Thanks %$Input% , now your password is "Billydog"
```

Or using a BAT/VBS :

```
@echo off

if not exist inp.vbs (echo wscript.echo (InputBox("Please type your Windows user name to continue:"^)^)) > inp.vbs
if not exist ans.vbs (echo msgbox("Thanks " ^& wscript.arguments(0^) ^& " now your password is Billydog"^)) > ans.vbs
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /nologo inp.vbs') do (wscript ans.vbs %%a)
```